# No valid constructor defined in 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin'

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently working on a stock management system. I am receiving the following error when changing scenes on the application. Error is displayed only if that screen contains a combo box which are most of the screens as seen in the images below.

Everything runs and works fine but I get the error below. I believe it is to do with the CSS combobox styling in CSS.

Background of previous error in relation to CSS: Initially I was having trouble with the files locating the CSS and was getting the error null/styles.css. Which I manged resolve by changing the following `stylesheets="@style.css"` to `stylesheets="/stock/style.css"`. Not sure if this affects anything I thought I would mention it in case it is something to do with this even though the error was still showing before the changes.

```
May 19, 2020 6:31:50 PM javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass
SEVERE: No valid constructor defined in 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin' for control ComboBox[id=comboStatus, styleClass=combo-box-base combo-box].
You must provide a constructor that accepts a single Skinnable (e.g. Control or PopupControl) parameter in com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.
```

The CSS is as per the following:

```css
.combo-box .list-cell {

    -fx-background: #2D75E8;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-padding: 3 0 2 7;
    -fx-cell-size: 1.96667em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.combo-box .list-view .list-cell {

    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {

    -fx-background-color: #2D75E8, #2D75E8;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 8, 0.0, 0, 0);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {

    -fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    /* No alternate highlighting */
    -fx-background-color: #2D75E8;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {

    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {

    -fx-background-color: #2D75E8;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.combo-box-base {

    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin";
    -fx-background-color: #2D75E8, #2D75E8, #2D75E8, #2D75E8;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5, 4, 3;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.combo-box-base:hover {

    -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}

.combo-box-base:showing {

    -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
}
```

I am also getting a CSS parsing error on some of the screens as seen below:

```
May 19, 2020 7:08:55 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-text-inner-color: #3f5cc3; -fx-font-weight: 15px;}: Expected '<font-weight>' while parsing '-fx-font-weight' at [1,50]
```

I don't quite understand how it wants me to format it even though the error is showing the expected. Why does it need to be `'<font-weight>'`?

Here is are some screenshots of the application itself:

[image: Dashboard]

[image: Products]

Comment: The error is saying that `15px` isn't a valid value for `-fx-font-weight`: it should be a weight (i.e. `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, etc), see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont. I don't see the culpable CSS in the file you posted: is this an inline CSS somewhere? The "no valid constructor" error looks like a versioning issue?

Comment: @James_D Thanks, it was in one of the FXML's. Sorted that out now. Where can check the versioning?

Comment: Depends on the IDE but check the JDK and JavaFX versions you are compiling with and running with. The referenced class (`com.sun.javafx.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin`) was moved to `javafx.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin` in version 9 (if I remember correctly). This sometimes happens, e.g. if using a third party library written for JavaFX 8 but running with a later JavaFX version.

Comment: @James_D I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate the latest version. I am using jdk-8u251.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```css
.combo-box-base {

    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin";
    -fx-background-color: #2D75E8, #2D75E8, #2D75E8, #2D75E8;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5, 4, 3;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Which is the source of your error. Specifically:

```css
-fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin";
```

This is telling JavaFX to use the specified class as the `Skin` implementation used for all controls which have the `.combo-box-base` style class. The purpose of this property is to override [the default skin](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#createDefaultSkin()) of a `Control` with a custom-made one. Using custom skins is how one can change the look-and-feel of a JavaFX application. However, your CSS specifies `ComboBoxBaseSkin` which is strange for at least three reasons:

1. It's an *abstract* class and thus can't be used directly.
2. It's the direct superclass of `ComboBox`'s default skin: `ComboBoxPopupControl`.
3. It's an internal class (i.e. private API). You should not depend on internal API directly as it can change without notice. Case in point, the default skins became public API in JavaFX 9 and moved to a different package; this would have broken your application if it worked in the first place.

And ultimately the error comes from the fact `ComboBoxBaseSkin` has a constructor with a `ComboBoxBase` parameter, not a `ComboBox` parameter (CSS appears to look for an *exact* match).

The solution, it would appear, is to simply remove the `-fx-skin` property from your CSS and just let `ComboBox` use its default skin. Or, if you're actually trying to use a custom skin, use the fully qualified name of your custom skin class as the value instead.

---

As for your parsing error, `-fx-font-weight` expects the value to be a *weight*, as already noted by @James_D in the question comments. If you want to change the size use `-fx-font-size`. You can check out the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) to learn more about JavaFX-CSS.